# Can I build off a branch blocked by a troll?

Tags: saboteur

Saboteur Duel adds Troll cards into the game where there is path, but one of the branches is blocked by a troll.

The rules state:

> The troll blocks the path behind it. If a player wants to pass a troll, he has to bribe it with 1 gold nugget.

My question is: can I build off the blocked branch?

As precedent for being able to build off a blocked branch I would point to the coloured door cards from Saboteur 2. Any player can build off of a path blocked by a coloured door, but if the gold is exposed through a path through a coloured door, only that team wins regardless of who plays the final card.

Would it be for paths blocked by trolls that I could build off the blocked path but not be able to collect any exposed gold until someone bribes the troll?

I assume the answer is 'no', but the rules aren't explicit on this point and there is some debate in my group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not covered in those rules but it is covered in the rules of the original game.

https://www.ultraboardgames.com/saboteur/game-rules.php

> Important: Newly placed path cards must always have an uninterrupted connection to the start card!

Since you are digging tunnels you will have to have a path to where you are digging the new one. Also it would greatly reduce the power of a card that blocks a path if you could continue building until you get a card to fix the blockage.